# Changing the Cursor for all objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am building an AJAX application that needs to change the cursor to a waiting cursor while waiting for the response to come in, and change back after. I know how to do that bit, but when the cursor is over links, or objects with custom cursors, those don't change, remaining as they were. Does anyone know how can I get the pointer to be the same for all objects temporarily?

Comment: apply the cursor style to the html or body tags maybe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
$('html').addClass('waiting');  // set waiting
// run ajax call... inside callback: 
$('html').removeClass('waiting');
```

In CSS:

```
html.waiting,
html.waiting * { cursor: wait !important; }
```

Comment: Jason beat me to the answer. Here's an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgCJw/).

Comment: @Micah, thanks for the example! I switched the example to use <html> instead of <body>, as the CSS won't apply to any part of the window below where the body (content) ends.  You may want to do the same in your example.  Furthermore, *always* use a tag selector (e.g. html.waiting instead of .waiting).  Performance is greatly improved.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the excellant feedback. I've updated the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DgCJw/1/).